# I have a problem I can't install package after I moved work folder storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm newbie in flutter

Because

image_picker >=0.8.6 depends on image_picker_platform_interface ^2.6.1 which depends on plugin_platform_interface
^2.1.0, image_picker >=0.8.6 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.1.0.
And because path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1 which depends on
plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, image_picker >=0.8.6 is incompatible with path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety.

So, because login_with_signup depends on both `path_provider ^1.6.5` and `image_picker ^0.8.7`, version solving failed.
pub get failed

```
command: "C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\dart \__deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\\src\\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
"PUB_CACHE": "C:\\Users\\zazac\\AppData\\Local\\Pub\\Cache",
}
exit code: 1
```

I tried to fix it but it didn't work.

It's my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: login_with_signup
description: Login With SignUp

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  toast: ^0.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  flutter_side_menu: ^0.3.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `any` keyword so the `packages get` will automatically pick versions that are compatible with one another; this is not a good practice but it's a fast solution for your problem. Generally, you should check for versions that are compatible.

```
  path_provider: any
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  toast: ^0.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  flutter_side_menu: ^0.3.0
  image_picker: any
```

Comment: now can fix it thank you very much